# Froala editor disable a button in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular6, editor, froala

I am using Froala editor in . my application, I want to disable a button in the dropdown of froala editor toolbar.

I have added an option to allow user to `align` content inside the editor, but I want to disable the 4th(Justify) option in `align` dropdown in toolbar, keeping only three options (left, centre, right).

```
FROALA_TOOLBAR_OPTIONS_FLASHCARDS = ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'color', '-',
        'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'insertImage', 'align'
    ];
```

I have tried searching through the docs. but didn't found anything useful that will allow me to disable the 4th option in `align` dropdown in `froala` toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hp0rsq52/

```
FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('custom_align', {NAME: 'cog', SVG_KEY: 'cogs'});
FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('custom_align', {
  title: 'Advanced options',
  type: 'dropdown',
  focus: false,
  undo: true,
  refreshAfterCallback: true,
  options: {
    'v1': 'left',
    'v2': 'center',
    'v3': 'right'
  },
    callback: function (cmd, val) {
    if (val == 'v1')
    {
      this.align.apply('left');
    }
    if (val == 'v2')
    {
      this.align.apply('center');
    }
    if (val == 'v3')
    {
      this.align.apply('right');
    }
  },

});

new FroalaEditor('div#froala-editor', {
   scaytCustomerId: '1:YjSV32-KWqTc2-AICoL3-WHiWO1-gYWRJ1-T1Cye3-Z9BJX3-YoRKY2-Icrlm-FMisd4-B26CZ3-SK3',
  toolbarButtons: [['undo', 'redo' , 'bold'], ['alert', 'clear', 'insert','custom_align']]
})
```